# Is have a "x" in a domain to join word a good idea?

Tags: design-patterns, urls

We all know there isn't much dictionary word .com domain out there, so many people are taking domains like my-clay.com or domain that has multi-words.

So currently I'm finding a domain, and expectedly it said unavailable, so I was thinking is using a "x" in a domain to join word a good idea?

For a example that uses x to join word is like AndyXapp (originally andyapp), is it a good try? Since I found out some magazine has use topics like sportXcamping

Comment: AndrewsApp.com (owned by Andrew Sapp) is up for renewal 1-11-18. There's no site there - wix parking spot. Try to buy it if he doesn't renew. If he does renew, contact him and see if he wants to sell it or trade for some help with his site.

Comment: @moot then why should we use AndrewsApp.com instead of AndrewApp.com, is there any benefits?

Comment: I wouldn't have even mentioned getting a different domain but AndrewsApp.com looks like the owner doesn't care about it. The owner has been getting notices to renew for a while now (90 days?) and they still haven't done it. I know it wasn't your question but a domain does eliminate the issue. AndrewApp.com is hosted, has a secondary domain, and isn't late for renewal - 11-2018.

Comment: This seems to be a marketing question, not a User Experience question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct is that this is a marketing question, and less directly a User Experience question. There are however some UX concerns with what you are asking that aren't exclusive of the marketing.

Branding: Is AndyXApp the brand you expect your users to find? Or is your current branding AndyApp where a search engine when queried with something like "Andy App to do Z' would return your site and possibly cause confusion? Especially when the following results are returned (and possibly others outranking your own site:

```
 AndyApp.com 
 AndyAppX.Com 
 AndyApp2.com
```

Security could be another concern, where random letters might look spammy to both the user AND spam filters. If this were and Android App for example, the user signs up for a service, through an App called "Andy". Will it be clear that AndyXApp.com or NoReply@AndyXApp.com is directly related to your site?

To wrap up, I'd avoid throwing a random letter in your domain just to get a domain name "close enough" to what you originally wanted.

```
1. As someone who has done sysadmin type work, it looks spammy and
   could be flagged as such
2. From a marketing perspective it seems to dilute your brand
3. For the UX part of the question, it seems much 
   more likely to cause confusion than help your user
4. Your users might not remember where that random letter went! Was it 
   XAndyApp or AndyAppX? What's this AndyXApp.com, that doesn't look 
   right at all!
```

I'd suggest looking at what the site/ app does and look to build the brand around that: For example "Andy's App to show the user great travel deals that Andy finds while browsing various travel sites" could be "AndyDoesDeals.com" or perhaps a help site for your application: "HelpForAndyApp.com"

And, for the sake of the question, both of these domains are available right now!

Answer (score 0):

I really love your concept to join the word by a letter but. **i don't think X is gonna work. As per my knowledge base people will read it ( AndyXapp ) including with the word X. so your brand name will be get change. as far i know X is treated as versions, models, assumption and more (Moto x, os X, iPhone X).**

and i even have some magazines, which have this type of things but.. its all about graphics and it will give a feeling of separating words but i don't think its gonna work on a domain because its a general text . **you cant differentiate by using font family properties or graphics contain in a domain name**.

So you may try some different extension or may be you may try google domain which offering  **.app (dot app)extension**.

Comment: But we can have site name like: **ANDY X APP** also this site: https://andrewxapp.weebly.com/